# how to call a global variable in a function in flask?

Tags: python, flask

[image]

Hello guys, small part of my code here, i have result and pred variables. And in the html part i have this code:

```
<div style = "margin-Top:100px;" class="container">
    
    {{ results[pred] }}

</div>
```

And i get this error. So how can i fix it?
So i thought the variable in html calling like that in flask. Am i wrong?

Comment: `results[pred]` is not a valid variable name. Change it to a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results[pred]` uses 2 variables to resolve:

- results, dict
- pred, the lookup in the dict

It seems, that u only need the value of pred in results. You can do this by using `return render_template('index.html', var=results[pred])` and `{{ var }}`

Edit: In your case pred is static in python so you should only return the mandotory value of the results dict to the template.

Comment: thanks, you explained very well, it was a simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t pass parameter like this.

In render_template pass result=result

And then in the template you can use it like you write - result[pred]